# Need super-basic help with motor encoder

Tags: arduino, motor, encoding, wiring

So I have this motor: https://www.servocity.com/23-rpm-hd-premium-planetary-gear-motor-w-encoder

and this motor shield for my arduino uno:
https://www.pololu.com/docs/pdf/0J49/dual_vnh5019_motor_driver_shield.pdf

And no background in electronics to speak of. I cannot find a basic enough resource to tell me where to attach the wires, or really what they each do. The ones that are simple enough for me only deal with motors with a couple of wires. Information on motors with six wires go immediately to discussing things that are way beyond me, or at least use terms that I don't know.

So the motor has six leads, and the only info I can find on them in the documentation are this: Black (Motor -), Red (Motor +), Green (Ground), Brown (Channel B), Yellow (Channel A), and Orange (Sensor Voltage +).

I have the black and red hooked up to M1A and M1B on my shield, so I am able to turn the motor on, vary its speed and direction. I also had all the other wires hooked up to various pins mentioned in the [Demo sketch associated with the shield](https://github.com/pololu/dual-vnh5019-motor-shield).

I have spent a week trying to figure this out on my own, but I am not getting anywhere (except that I know that hooking up orange to almost anything triggers a fault).

So in addition to the four wires that are not connected to anything, I have these pins mentioned in the sketch that are also not connected to wires: D2 M1INA, D4 M1INB, D6 M1EN/DIAG, D9 M1PWM and A0 M1CS.

I hope someone can provide a pointer to a resource or a good, plain-language explanation for what these wires and pin descriptions mean. Thanks in advance!

## servocity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Green (Ground), Brown (Channel B), Yellow (Channel A), and Orange (Sensor Voltage +)" wires connect to the encoder on the back of the motor and allow the use of quadrature to detect the number and direction of motor turns.

As noted on [servocity's page for the motor](https://www.servocity.com/23-rpm-hd-premium-planetary-gear-motor-w-encoder), you can count the following numbers of cycles or events per rotation of the motor or of the output shaft:

```
Encoder: Cycles Per Revolution (Motor Shaft)                12
Encoder: Cycles Per Revolution (Output Shaft)            4,428
Encoder: Countable Events Per Revolution (Motor Shaft)      48
Encoder: Countable Events Per Revolution (Output Shaft) 17,712
```

An "event" refers to an edge, up or down, on either of the encoder channels.  A "cycle" refers to the two channels going through the four phases of one quadrature-encoder cycle.

Given the gear ratio 369:1, the motor probably spins about 8500 RPM to make 23 RPM on the output shaft.  A software-based quadrature decoder might have trouble keeping up with 6800 events per second (ie, 48*8500 = 408000 events per minute, or 1/60 as many per second) if the Arduino will be doing anything else besides quadrature decoding.  You could combine some of the code shown at [an arduino.stackexchange answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/18221/3917) with that at [another arduino.stackexchange answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/16420/3917) to see how many events per second you could count using software on an Arduino.  The 147 microseconds available per event (ie, 1000000 us / 6800 events) might or might not be enough; most likely you will need to use a hardware-based quadrature decoder and counter to track shaft location.

[Edit 3:] If the motor parameter you wish to control or measure is speed rather than position, a typical ATmega328-based Arduino board can count enough encoder events to give that information for a single motor.  For example, if using an Uno you could connect one encoder line to PD5, the T1 input pin on a '328.  With the motor running at full speed, Counter 1 would overflow about twice a second.  In its interrupt handler you would read the current value of micros, store it in a volatile variable, and set a change flag.  The interrupt handler could also add or subtract the counter value to a position total.

[Edit 2:] Regarding the wiring, it appears that you should do like the following:

```
Pin# Color   Function             Hook to...
3.   Green   (Ground),               common ground
4.   Brown   (Channel B),            quad. decoder input 2
5.   Yellow  (Channel A),            quad. decoder input 1
6.   Orange  (Sensor Voltage +)      V+ (eg to logic +5 or +12)
```

See [wikipedia's Rotary Encoder article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder#Incremental_rotary_encoder) for more discussion of quadrature encoding/decoding, along with signal diagrams, etc.

See [pololu's "Using the Driver in Single-Channel Mode"](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J49/7) page for an explanation of pins like M1INA, M1INB, M1EN, etc.

Comment: It took me a while, but I think I see what you meant. I corrected the physical connections and used the first code example you suggested to read in milliseconds how long Channels A and B were open. I am (slowly) starting to extract from the second code sample how to count pulses instead of their durations. After I get all that done, I will connect my second motor and get both counting. At that point, I expect I will have totally swamped the arduino and will have to figure out a separate piece of hardware to do the encoder. But thank you so much for the toe-hold on this, I was way off course!

Comment: @sparse, I added a paragraph about using counter/timer 1 to measure motor speed.  A typical Arduino can do that without being swamped.

Comment: I corrected events-per-second from 400000 to 6800, per comments/edit by @Michael Snower.  Thanks!  Also showed the calculation.